# buffer of clusters in a sparse matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, buffer, sparse-matrix, raster

I work with MATLAB.
I have a sparse matrix where I identified different clusters. The value within each cluster is equal, while each cluster has its own unique value. I have 0s as background (outside clusters). Here is an example with clusters 1 and 2:

```
A=(000002002000
   110002222000
   111000222200
   110000022000
   111000000000)
```

I'd like to use each cluster as "a polygon" and study the value of the outside neighbor pixels (a sort of buffer as in vector data). Obviously in the example it would output 0 as mean all the time, but the point is understanding how to do it, as I have to apply this to another matrix (I work with geolocated data, so I would use the buffer area to find mean values in specific rasters). Is there a way to do that? Also, if so, can I specify the width of this buffer (as number of pixels)?

Comment: use morphological operations `bwmorph`, `bwlabel` and `regionprops` will help you.

Comment: thanks for the input. I came up with a good result using bwperim (which returns the perimeter of an object as 1s), then using bwdist against the perimeter and selecting only the 1s. Then, to retain only the outer extent of the perimeter I erased everything left inside by buffer(A~=0)=0.

Comment: umbe1987, better to include additional information on what you did in the question itself. Also, since you "came up with a good result" – what's missing?